# Потоки в Spring. Не могу разобраться с ThreadLocal

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring

Не могу понять как это вообще работает. Использую `ThreadLocal<>`. Простой пример:

**Secure Bean**

```
public class SecureBean {
    public void writeSecureMessage() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

**UserInfo.java**

```
public class UserInfo {
    private String name;
    private String password;
   /* Геттеры и сеттеры */
}
```

**SimpleSecurityManager**

```
public class SimpleSecurityManager implements SecurityManager {
    private static ThreadLocal<UserInfo> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public void login(String userName, String userPassword) {
        threadLocal.set(new UserInfo(userName, userPassword));
    }

    public void logout() {
        threadLocal.set(null);
    }

    public UserInfo getLoggedOnUser() {
        return threadLocal.get();
    }
}
```

**SecurityAdvise.java**

```
public class SecurityAdvise implements MethodBeforeAdvice {
    private SecurityManager securityManager;

    @Override
    public void before(Method method, Object[] objects, Object o) throws Throwable {
        UserInfo user = securityManager.getLoggedOnUser();

        if (user == null) {
            System.out.println("No user auth");
            throw new SecurityException(
                    "You must be logged to attempt to invoke this method: " + method.getName()
            );
        } else if ("admin".equals(user.getName())) {
            System.out.println("Logged user is admin - OK!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Bad user!");
            throw new SecurityException(
                    "You must be logged to attempt to invoke this method: " + method.getName()
            );
        }
    }

    public void setSecurityManager(SecurityManager securityManager) {
        this.securityManager = securityManager;
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean("securityManager")
    public SecurityManager securityManager() {
        return new SimpleSecurityManager();
    }

    @Bean("securityAdvise")
    public SecurityAdvise securityAdvise() {
        SecurityAdvise advise = new SecurityAdvise();
        advise.setSecurityManager(securityManager());
        return advise;
    }

    @Bean("secureBean")
    public SecureBean secureBean() {
        SecureBean target = new SecureBean();
        SecurityAdvise advise = securityAdvise();
        ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
        proxyFactory.setTarget(target);
        proxyFactory.addAdvice(advise);
        return (SecureBean) proxyFactory.getProxy();
    }
}
```

**Application.java(Работает)**

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        SecureBean secureBean = (SecureBean) context.getBean("secureBean");
        SecurityManager securityManager = (SecurityManager) context.getBean("securityManager");

        securityManager.login("admin", "pass");
        secureBean.writeSecureMessage();
        securityManager.logout();
    }
}
```

**Application.java(Всё так же работает)**

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        SecureBean secureBean = (SecureBean) context.getBean("secureBean");
        SecurityManager securityManager = (SecurityManager) context.getBean("securityManager");

        securityManager.login("admin", "pass");
        new ThreadLocal<UserInfo>().set(new UserInfo("Wrong username", "Another thread?"));
        secureBean.writeSecureMessage();
        securityManager.logout();
    }
}
```

**Application.java(Опять же работает)**

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        SecureBean secureBean = (SecureBean) context.getBean("secureBean");
        SecurityManager securityManager = new SecurityManager();

        securityManager.login("admin", "pass");
        secureBean.writeSecureMessage();
        securityManager.logout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определение [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html):

> Этот класс предоставляет локальные переменные потока. Эти переменные
>   отличаются от их обычных аналогов тем, что каждый поток, который
>   обращается к нему (посредством метода `get` или `set`), имеет свою
>   собственную, независимо инициализированную копию переменной.
>   Экземпляры `ThreadLocal` обычно представляют собой частные статические
>   поля в классах, которые хотят связать состояние с потоком (например,
>   идентификатор пользователя или идентификатор транзакции).

По вашему коду видно, что вы можете вызывать метод `writeSecureMessage()` если имя пользователя `admin`.

`ThreadLocal` здесь используется, чтобы нельзя это было делать из другого потока. То есть, если вы создаете новый поток, то вам опять надо делать `login("admin",)`.